# Unescape string Python for MySQL

Tags: python-2.7, mysql-python

I have used `from MySQLdb import escape_string` to escape a string.
How can I unescape the string to get the original string back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `"your string".decode("string_escape")`

```
>>> escaped_string = "Hello\\nThere"
>>>
>>> unescaped_string = escaped_string.decode("string_escape")
>>>
>>> escaped_string
'Hello\\nThere'
>>>
>>> unescaped_string
'Hello\nThere'
```

Comment: @AminahNuraini are you using python 2.7 as the question is about?

Comment: I forgot when did I downvote this. Was I already migrate or no. It was impossible to not migrate

Answer (score -1):

I do it this way

```
import ast

a = 'Hello\\nThere'
print(ast.literal_eval('"""{}"""'.format(a)))
```